# Android Internet Sometimes Seems Like Sleeping

Tags: android

I am developer android app that uses parse server and several other APIs which requires internet connection. The problem is, sometimes it seems like the device internet connection is "sleeping".

Most of the times, when I first opened the app, things will go very slow, feels like the internet isn't working, loading data over the internet goes very slow. But eventually it will "wake up" and work fast. It will also always work fast if I disconnect and connect again to the wifi.

There is no problem with the parse server or APIs as I have confirmed them. My device is also connected to a stable wifi.

Is there any way to trigger the device to make sure the internet connection is "awake"? My device is xiaomi with android 5.1.1.

Comment: The chip that handles the network activity will enter in a sleep mode to prevent battery usage if there is no request to handle. And it will wake up when it needs to handle something staying a little in this state, after it going back to sleep. I think that this might be the problem. Also, make sure to check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEEulSk1kNY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you turn on the battery saver? I have LG G3 and my applications and sometimes the internet services are stopped when battery saver is turned on , using Android 6.0......

Comment: Hello, I have checked on this before and it's turned off.